# NScrollView don't work with opened image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsscrollview

I have scrollview added with interface builder its implemented in `NSWindow` view and in `NSScrollview` i added CustomView i'm using this code line in my

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib

id docView = paintingfield;
id viewas = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:
                            [[scrollview contentView] frame]];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
[scrollview setDocumentView:docView];
[scrollview setContentView:viewas];
```

an in my AppDelegate.h

```
IBOutlet NSScrollView * scrollview;
IBOutlet NSView * view;
IBOutlet CustomView *paintingfield;
```

`IBOutlets` are linked propertly `NSScrollView` to `NSScrollView`, `NSView` to CustomView, CustomView to CustomView.
`-awakeFromNib` is called
the problem is because of `NSScrollView` when i open image i get blank window instead of opened image with scroll without `NSScrollView` image opens proper too any ideas how can i fix it?

Comment: try remove the line [scrollview setContentView:viewas];

Comment: if i remove this line i get empty window without any View or Opened image

Comment: hmm but after i remove this line and Custom view from NSScrollView in interface i get a Opened image with some kind of scroll view i will try to work with that now

Comment: and image is not opening correctly because this line sets frame of contentview

Comment: this line is unnecessary anyway.

Comment: you should set up content size like this: [scrollView.documentView setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,_width, _height) ]; . where _width and _heigt is size of painting field.

Comment: and i should set this in open image method?

Comment: and this line is important because i will use it to center my Custom View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change you code like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
    [scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
    [scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [scrollview setDocumentView:paintingfield];
    [scrollView.documentView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, paintingfield.frame.size.width,paintingfield.frame.size.height) ];
}
```

Comment: it works but only if i put this line in open image method thanks for help!